# .getJSON works just one time on mobiles

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have a .getJSON() function which fires on button click (random record from DB). It works fine for desktop, but on mobile devices works just **one time**. Then it keeps delivering the same record. I guess it even doesn't do a AJAX call to php because random.php file creates a JSON file every time php is requested.. and on mobile requests the JSON file is not created..

jQuery part:

```
    $("#random_post").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("random.php",function(result){
          $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("#selected-name").text("Name: ".concat(field.name));
            $("#selected-link").text("Link: ".concat(field.link));
            $("#selected-date").text("Date: ".concat(field.date));
            $("#selected-content").text("Content: ".concat(field.content));
            $("#selected-video").text("Video: ".concat(field.video));             
          });
        });

    });
```

PHP delivery part is usual:

```
echo json_encode($data);
$fp = fopen('results2.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
fclose($fp);
```

The button is **Random post** at http://raigle.com/a.php

Comment: @Pinch where and how should I do that?

Comment: just a suggestion too, your `$("#random_post").click` should `return false`

Comment: @jeremy I played with that, no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caching, use `$.ajax` instead ([docs here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) `$.getJSON` is just a wrapper (and in my option not a very good one) for this function anyway.

```
$.ajax({cache:false,
    url:"random.php",
    dataType :'json'})
    .done(function(result){
      .....etc
    });
```